# Maximum secret key length from a time series shared signal

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis, entropy, perfect-secrecy

Alice and Bob share a common time series signal.

**1. What can be the largest possible secret key?**

**2. Will the entropy and secrecy of system depends on this length?**

Ideally if after passing though analog to digital converter(ADC) number of bits a signal gives depends on $N_S$ sampling rate. Suppose I had s 1 second window of signal. Through ADC I got $N_S$ samples. I apply threshold on these samples and generate keys. Maximum length hence is $N_S$ bits of secret keys.

Is this the best key? I mean is there any relation between entropy/secrecy of the key vs length I choose from $N_S$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. What can be the largest possible secret key?

Any size. You can use the entropy as input for a DRBG (deterministic random bit generator) or KDF (key derivation function) and generate as many bits you want out of that.

> 2. Will the entropy and secrecy of system depends on this length?

No.

> Assumption: Maximum length hence is $N_S$ bits of secret keys

No, it isn't. That's just the input data that contains *a certain amount* of entropy - or at least that's what we'll assume for the sake of argument.

> 3. Is this the best key?

No $N_S$ (or any specific part of $N_S$) is not the best key. You want to explicitly *extract* the randomness from your data. $N_S$ may be biased.